# Is it possible to pass a vector<shared_ptr<T>> to a const vector<shared_ptr<const T>>& parameter?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, constants, shared-ptr

Suppose we have the following function:

```
void doStuff(const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<const Foo>>& fs) { }
```

Is there a way to (safely) pass a `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Foo>>` to this parameter? For instance:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Foo>> foos;
doStuff(foos);
```

This implicit conversion fails, but can it be done safely with a cast? (This seems theoretically safe because the `doStuff` function will not be able to modify the vector, nor the objects inside it.)

Comment: I find that making shared_ptr of const items adds unnecessary complexity.  But I don't think you can do this without a hack.

Comment: This is definitively undefined behavior. Memory layout wise it might *looks like* it should work every time, but you can't rely on that. Who knows what transformation the compiler might do, including eliding any code that presents undefined behavior.

Comment: What is undefined behavior? The code in my question doesn't compile, so perhaps you are referring to some hypothetical `const_cast`?

Comment: @jtbandes Apologizes, I was referring to a hypothetical `reinterpret_cast` or c cast. I don't see how a `const_cast` can solve this. If it was just a `const_cast` it could be well defined. `const_cast` can't convert from `std::vector<const T>&` to `std::vector<T>&`.

Comment: @AnonMail I see how it can add complexity, but omitting `const` here would  also allow the callee to modify the underlying objects. Is there some way to avoid that? I suppose if `shared_ptr` had only `T* operator->();` and `const T* operator->() const;` then it would work as intended with `const vector<shared_ptr<T>>`, but that is not the case...

Comment: @jtbandes are you saying doStuff is a callback into user code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is "No".

Given a class template

```
template <typename T> struct Foo {};
```

`Foo<int>` and `Foo<const int>` are two different types. There is no implicit conversion between the two types.

My recommendation would be to make `doStuff` a function template.

```
template <typename T>
void doStuff(const std::vector<T>& fs) { }
```

or

```
template <typename T>
void doStuff(const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>>& fs) { }
```

If you don't have the option of modifying `doStuff`, duplicating the code from `doStuff` for `shared_ptr<Foo>` is probably the only sane thing to do.

Comment: I understand that the implicit conversion doesn't work, but I'm asking if there is some way to use explicit casts safely here.

Comment: as a workaround it might be worth looking into `std::transform`(http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) and change doSomething to take one item at a time and cast it to the proper type.

Answer (score 0):

No. But what you can do instead is change your interface to be more inclusive. You write:

```
void doStuff(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Foo const>> const& fs) { }
```

But what you really want is just some contiguous range of `std::shared_ptr<const Foo>` right? So let's change that to:

```
void doStuff(gsl::span<std::shared_ptr<Foo const>> fs) { }
```

But then really, do we need the shared pointers themselves to point to `const` or is it enough that they are `const`?

```
void doStuff(gsl::span<std::shared_ptr<Foo> const> fs) { }
```

And now we have an interface that we can call with `std::vector<shared_ptr<Foo>>`.